# Multiple jfreecharts display same data

Tags: java, jfreechart

Im currently working on a statistical modeling program for a game (League of Legends) that outputs a bar graph for an input player name that displays metrics for Kills, Deaths, and Assists with regard to champion.

My issue is this: I have a class `BarChart_AWT` that contains a function `display(Player player)` that prints out the described graph for a given player. Right now, I am using the `display(Player player)` function as such:

```
BarChart_AWT.display(player1);
BarChart_AWT.display(player2);
```

And yet these two separate function calls return identical graphs, which I know should not the case. See output below.

[image: Output Graphs]

My class `BarChart_AWT` is included below. If anyone can help me identify why I am having this issue, I would be much appreciative. Thanks!

```
public class BarChart_AWT extends ApplicationFrame
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public BarChart_AWT( String applicationTitle , String chartTitle, Vector<championClass> vect )
    {

        super( applicationTitle );        
        JFreeChart barChart = ChartFactory.createBarChart(
            chartTitle,           
            "Champion",            
            "Value",            
            createDataset(vect),          
            PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,           
            true, true, false);

        ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel( barChart );        
        chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension( 560 , 367 ) );        
        setContentPane( chartPanel ); 
     }

    //Populates graph with data
    private CategoryDataset createDataset( Vector<championClass> cVector)
    {
        final DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset( );

        //Define Bars
        final String kills = "Kills";        
        final String deaths = "Deaths";        
        final String assists = "Assists"; 

        for (Enumeration<championClass> e = cVector.elements(); e.hasMoreElements();)
        {
            championClass current = e.nextElement();
            final String championName = current.getName();
            dataset.addValue(current.getKills(), kills, championName);
            dataset.addValue(current.getDeaths(), deaths, championName);
            dataset.addValue(current.getAssists(), assists, championName);
        }

        return dataset; 
    }

    public static void display(Player player) {
        BarChart_AWT playerChart = new BarChart_AWT("Champion data for: " + player.getName(), "Performance by Champion", player.getVector());
        playerChart.pack( );        
        RefineryUtilities.positionFrameOnScreen(playerChart, 25, 25);       
        playerChart.setVisible( true );
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't spot the mistake... Are you 100% sure that `display()` gets called with 2 different players? A self-contained piece of code would be ideal...

Comment: Absent [*correct synchronization*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html), any result may occur; it may even look OK in a debugger.